# How do you return a plain text string from an ORDS REST endpoint?

Tags: json, oracle, rest, http, response

When creating a REST Data Services module handler in Oracle Rest Data Services (ORDS), it auto-formats the response as a JSON for PL/SQL procedures -- that is, any OUT parameters that you create get turned into a JSON. How do you return a plain-text string in the HTTP response without it being turned into a JSON?

A lot of my initial searches point to [this resource](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/09/ords-returning-raw-json/) for returning a raw JSON in ORDS, but this doesn't work for my situation since you can't change the **Source Type** if you're writing a PL/SQL endpoint (e.g. a method handler that's not auto-generated from a database object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, I found [this documentation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-http-headers-and-ords-specific-bind-variables) which is for something else entirely; *however*, it shows some example code using the `HTP.p()` method to print plain-text directly to the response. Below is a simple example of how to return a plain-text response in your ORDS REST Data Services module method handler:

```
BEGIN
  OWA_UTIL.mime_header('text/plain');
  HTP.p('Hello world!');
END;
```